# how to do netcat in a terminal

Tags: bash, debian, netcat

i have a program that is like a terminal that i want always on, how do i put it in a port through `netcat` so when i connect to that port i can write in the terminal and when i exit, the program doesn't close?
could you help me?

Comment: Do you also want the output from the program to be passed via `netcat` in the opposite direction than your input? By "doesn't close", do you mean "doesn't close" *only*? or *additionally* "it's able to accept another connection and work as if the client never disconnected"? What if there are two or more connection attempts at the same time?

Comment: only one connection and by  doesnt close i mean the program doesnt close